# What is good strategy to make a flexible layout for Landscape and Portrait orientation and should also work well in Desktop?

Tags: css, mobile-safari

Currently I use fixed `width:960px` because I want to keep the layout centered in desktop. but doing this it makes problem in iPad portrait mode. I need to re-define widht to `768px` and also do adjustments for according to that.

is there a way to make a flexible layout for **Desktop + iPad ( Portrait + Landscape mode) with minimal code and minimal efforts.

Answer (score 1):

This might help.. http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/ipad-layout-with-landscape-portrait-modes

Comment: But I'm already using this technique `
#wrap {
   width:1024px;
}
@media only screen and (orientation:portrait){
   /* portrait styles here */
   #wrap {
      width:768px;
   }
}` I want to make a flexible layout without using different width for Portrait mode

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem. But how about min-width and max-width ?

Comment: I want to shrink the layout in portrait mode automatically

Comment: It happens in portrait mode automatically.. thats why they use different sizes and other css for portrait mode and lanscape mode. Well, i suppose technically its zooming out.. but thats why they use different widths...

Comment: but when we use  `#wrap { width:768px; }` we also need to adjust all the items inside `#wrap`

Comment: I'm asking in question about How to make  all things inside `#wrap` flexible. so they can adjust automatically.

Comment: @Lollero let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2615/discussion-between-jitendra-vyas-and-lollero)